# Showing that a chart is smooth compatible

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In my notes:

[image]

It is claimed that $f^{-1}_{+}\left ( x \right )=\left ( x,\sqrt{1-x^{2}} \right )$. I am unable to understand how this is derived.
Equally so, I am unable to understand why the range of the map is restricted to the open interval of 0 and 1.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
f^{-1}_{+}\left ( x \right )=\left ( x,\sqrt{1-x^{2}} \right )
\end{equation}

because $f_{+}$ is a projection, it takes points of $S^1$ (actually points in the upper half circumference) and it projects them on the x-axis between $(-1,1)$; $f^{-1}_{+}$ takes $x\in(-1,1)$ and it brings them in the upper half circumference, so $f^{-1}_{+}$ has the upper half circumference as range and every point of this range has $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\in(0,1]$. You can obtain $f^{-1}_{+}$ from the equation of the circumference $x^2+y^2=1$:

\begin{equation}
y^2=1-x^2\\
y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{equation}

You choose $+$ because $f^{-1}_{+}$ has the upper half circumference as range.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.
On a related page,
note that $U_{+}\cap V_{+} \subseteq U_{+}$ and $U_{+}{\cap}V_{+}\subseteq V_{+}$.

So by construction of the map, $f^{+}$ is a map from $U_{+}$ to $\left ( -1,1 \right )$ and $g^{+}$ is a map from $V_{+}$ to $\left ( -1,1 \right )$.
I think we can agree that what follows from my above argument will conjoin with your argument. However, are there any potential issues with my above argument that I have failed to consider or is it just convoluted without good reason(s)?

Comment: Is the range in the upper half circumference $\left ( 0,1 \right )$ or $\left ( 0,1 \right ]$?

Comment: $y\in(0,1]$ in the upper half circumference. $x=0$ is mapped to the point $(x=0,y=1)$

Comment: However it's true, the maps $f^+$ and $g^+$ overlap in $\{(x,y)\in S^1: x,y>0\}$ i.e. in the arc of the circumference of the first quadrant.